# How to store a react element in a variable and render it elsewhere?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have a component `ComponentCreator` which creates a state and another component `component`.

```
const ComponentCreator = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const component = <input
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />

  return component;

}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <ComponentCreator />
    </>
  );
}
```

This works fine.

Now what I want is to somehow share the `component` between other components. It is important that the state

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
```

stays inside the `ComponentCreator` and it is not lifted up.

So how could I render the `component` to lets say the `App` component ?

I tried this:

```
const ComponentCreator = ({setC}) => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const component = <input
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />

  useEffect(() => {
    setC(component);
  }, [])

  return component;

}

export default function App() {

  const [c, setC] = useState(null);
  return (
    <>
    {c}
    <ComponentCreator setC={setC} />
    </>
  );
}
```

but it is not working. I am getting a really weird behavior where I can only type one letter in the input component of `App` but still working fine inside `ComponentCreator`.

How can I achieve this ?

[EDIT]

Answering to comments:

The reason I want this is the following.

I want a component to trigger a method `createDialogWithConent` with "fire and forget" approach.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  const component = <input
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />

...
<button onClick={ () => createDialogWithContent({content: component}) } ... />
...
```

and the the dialog would render the content

```
const DialogWrapper = () => {
   const { content: component } = useDialogContent();

   return <Dialog>
       {component}
      <Dialog />
```

So the component which triggers the `createDialogWithContent` has access to `[value, setValue]` so it can use it in a later time, and also this state can be changed when the dialog pops up.

Comment: What's the reason you want to do this? Are you hoping that all the inputs will have a shared value that updates in unison? As you've found out, storing elements in state makes it very easy to have stale-data bugs, so if there's another approach to solving your goals you should avoid putting elements in state.

Comment: this would be lead to over engineered code and anti pattern to pass react component as props and state

Comment: @NicholasTower The reason I want this is to call a function ```createDialogWithContent( { content: x } )``` with fire and forget approach. But I want to be able to both have the state of component ```x``` and still be available inside a ```<Dialog />``` global component. So a user can edit the input inside the dialog, and the component which triggered the ```createDialogWithContent``` can do something in a later time with the ```[value, setValue]``` state.

Comment: What you are trying to do sounds like you better introduce a `store` (this does not necessairily need to be redux, any store will do; might even just be a global var or just a `useRef`). You can define any component to write to the store, and you can access the store later even after the component has been destoyed and garbage-collected.